# why is sublime not capable of detecting ruby methods?

Tags: ruby

well after installing ruby, i started to use sublime and whenever i try to build the simplest program, sublime cannot find any method.

[image]

as you can see it's saying undefined method chomp.

I installed ruby with RubyInstaller under C:/Ruby

thanks.

Comment: `gets` requires an `STDIN` pretty sure `sublime_text` is not interactive like that so this will not work. On the other hand if you run this from cmd as ruby /path/to/script.rb it should work just fine.

Comment: expanding on other comment, since there is no stdin `gets` is returning `nil`. `nil` does not have a `chomp` method.

Comment: @engineersmnky so i can never build from sublime directly?

Comment: You can but you cannot use user input in this way. People have suggested an interactive shell for Sublime text but it is just that as of right now.

Comment: No problem to test simple things like this you can also always use irb. from cmd type irb and you will be inside the Ruby Interactive Shell